# Laravel, how do I get the array values using their index?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How do I get array values using their index, that is, using index 0 until 20 as shown in the picture below. I wanted to get the specific value, using index number 3 for example.

[image]

Comment: something like `$data[3] ` just like other arrays

Comment: You can use `foreach` to loop through all those data or you can use specific indexes (`$array[0]` or `$array[3]`) to access the data.

Comment: okay that solved my prob, thanks guys...now how do i upvote this comment?

Comment: @SougataBose You should post this as answer so He can mark this question as answered or

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi Actually I am not sure what OP actually wants and how the approach sould be.

Comment: it is exactly what @SagarGautam said

Comment: @begineeeerrrr your question seems unclear, permit me to make modification to the question and tell me if it still expresses the same thing

Comment: @begineeeerrrr I will suggest that you read more on arrays here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php You will find more answers to potential questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,];
```

You want the array number 5, so just do:

```
$data = array_keys($my_array, 5);
```

Comment: Though this might answer the question, please also add a short explanation what your code does and why it solves the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
foreach( $array as $index => $element )
{ 'show'. $index . '=>'. $element }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30340136)

Answer (score -1):

Try this: Suppose you have $data as array and you want to print 3rd element then $data[3] will give you 3rd element.

Comment: `$data[3]` would give you the 4th element.